# How to decode NSData on iOS with RSA key?

Tags: ios, encoding, rsa, nsdata, decoding

I like to know how to `decrypt` (and `encrypt`) `NSData` with an `RSA key`? I have know idea how to do this. Is there already a build in methode in the normal iOS Frameworks?

Comment: do you mean decrypt and encrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in your project: `<CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>` and try the function `CCCrypt`. You can find tha man page [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CCCryptor)

Comment: OK, I worked it out, I can encrypt and decrypt the NSData on one idevice, but when I create a QR code with the encrypted NSData and read it on another iOS device and encrypt it with the same key I get an invalide NSData. The encrypted string is the same, but I cant decode it, do you know any fix?